# Wrong output in parsing Date from DateFormat Using Calendar

Tags: java, android, datetime, calendar, simpledateformat

What is wrong with my code i couldn't get the exact output from the date time that i want to be parsed?

```
String convertDate="03/19/2014 5:30:10 PM";
DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss", Locale.CANADA);
Date myDate=new Date();
try {
    myDate=df.parse(convertDate);
    final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
    c.setTime(myDate);
    System.out.println("Year = " + c.get(Calendar.YEAR));
    System.out.println("Month = " + (c.get(Calendar.MONTH)));

    System.out.println("Day = " + c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));
} catch (ParseException e1) {
    e1.printStackTrace();
}
```

And my output is

```
 - 04-28 03:07:15.322: I/System.out(25095): Year = 2015
 - 04-28 03:07:15.322: I/System.out(25095): Month = 6
 - 04-28 03:07:15.322: I/System.out(25095): Day = 3
```

it must be

```
 - Year = 2014
 - Month = 03
 - Day = 19
```

Comment: Remember that c.get(Calendar.MONTH) is zero based (i.e., January is month 0, etc).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss", Locale.CANADA);
```

Now try... It'll work.

With this you have to add 1 with your month. code is here:

```
 String convertDate="03/19/2014 5:30:10 PM";
         DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss", Locale.CANADA);
         Date myDate=new Date();
         try {
            myDate=df.parse(convertDate);
            final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
            c.setTime(myDate);
            int y,m,d;
            y=Calendar.YEAR;
            System.out.println("Year = " + c.get(Calendar.YEAR));
            //Log.d("Year", y);
            System.out.println("Month = " + (c.get(Calendar.MONTH)+1));

            System.out.println("Day = " + c.get(Calendar.DATE));
        } catch (ParseException e1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Comment: "MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss" is not a format for "03/19/2014 5:30:10 PM" also the result still wrong, this time Month = 2 it should be Month = 3

Comment: what do you mean to format my code..? i already change my Formatter to DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss aa", Locale.CANADA);

Answer (score 2):

Change your date format from this

```
dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss
```

to this

```
MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss
```

And month is `Zero (0)` index based. So, after retrieving month index you must have to add `1` to get current month.

So, try to print current month as follows...

```
int currentMonth = c.get(Calendar.MONTH) + 1;

System.out.println("Month = " + currentMonth);
```

Or

```
System.out.println("Month = " + (c.get(Calendar.MONTH)+1));
```

Comment: i also tried that but still it was an wrong output it gives me an Month = 21

Comment: i already change my Formatter to DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss aa", Locale.CANADA);

Comment: The `Month` index and `1` was concated as `String` that's why output was `21`.

Comment: it's my mistake i did not add an parenthesis.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, [the accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23332039/10819573) as well [the other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23332270/10819573) are wrong.

You have done two mistakes in parsing:

1. You have swapped `MM` with `dd`.
2. You have used `H` instead of `h` to parse a date-time string with AM/PM marker. The symbol, `H` is used to parse a time string in 24-Hour format. Another **important point** to consider is that PM is written as `p.m.` in `Locale.CANADA`. For your time string, you can use `Locale.US` which specifies it as PM.

Thus, you can use a parser like the one given below:

```
new SimpleDateFormat("M/d/u h:m:s a", Locale.US)
```

where `a` has been used to parse AM/PM.

Using this parser will fix your problem but the legacy date-time API (`java.util` date-time types and their formatting API, `SimpleDateFormat`) is outdated and error-prone. It is recommended to stop using it completely and switch to `java.time`, the [modern date-time API](https://www.oracle.com/technical-resources/articles/java/jf14-date-time.html)<sup>*</sup>.

**Demo using modern date-time API:**

```
import java.time.LocalDateTime;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;
import java.util.Locale;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        String convertDate = "03/19/2014 5:30:10 PM";
        DateTimeFormatter dtfInput = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("M/d/u h:m:s a", Locale.US);
        LocalDateTime ldt = LocalDateTime.parse(convertDate, dtfInput);
        System.out.printf("Year: %d, Month: %d, Day: %d%n", ldt.getYear(), ldt.getMonthValue(), ldt.getDayOfMonth());

        // Or, using DateTimeFormatter
        DateTimeFormatter dtfOutput = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("'Year:' uuuu, 'Month:' M, 'Day:' d", Locale.US);
        System.out.println(ldt.format(dtfOutput));
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
Year: 2014, Month: 3, Day: 19
Year: 2014, Month: 3, Day: 19
```

Learn more about the the [modern date-time API](https://www.oracle.com/technical-resources/articles/java/jf14-date-time.html)<sup>*</sup> from **[Trail: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/index.html)**.

---

<sup>* For any reason, if you have to stick to Java 6 or Java 7, you can use [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) which backports most of the *java.time* functionality to Java 6 & 7. If you are working for an Android project and your Android API level is still not compliant with Java-8, check [Java 8+ APIs available through desugaring](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support-table) and [How to use ThreeTenABP in Android Project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38922754/how-to-use-threetenabp-in-android-project).</sup>